# Redirect to intended page before Asked to login

Tags: django, django-login

Let me modify this question

I have a my own login view as below and am implementing the `@login_required` decorator.

```
def do_login(request):
form = LoginForm()# create an instance of a login form
logged_in =request.user.is_authenticated() # get login status

if logged_in:
    message='You are logged in '
    return render_to_response('login.html',locals())# return  
if request.method == 'POST':
    usr=request.POST['username'] #get username
    passwrd=request.POST['password']# get password
    form=LoginForm(request.POST) # create instance of loginform
    user=authenticate(username=usr,password=passwrd)# authenticate user
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request,user) #log user in
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/login_success/")
        else:
            pass
    else:
        return render_to_response('login.html',locals())
else:
    return render_to_response('login.html',locals())
```

This works, as anytime I try to visit a url (for example to change password)am taken to the loggin page to log in first. While at the login page the url that appears in the address bar is `http://myapp.com/login/?next=/change_password/`

Now when I login am taken to `http://myapp.com/login/login_success/` instead of `http://myapp.com/login/change_password/`. Upon loggin in I want to be automatically redirected to the intended `http://myapp.com/login/change_password/` I tried to get to before asked to login. How do I solve this please

Comment: Why are you putting csrf_ exempt decorators everywhere? There's a reason for CSRF protection, you shouldn't disable it without a very good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this

Template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'some_summary_url' %}">click me</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={% url 'some_summary_url' %}">click me</a>
{% endif %}
```

View:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next', '/'))
```

Comment: I want to access the next parameter in my view so I can use `return HttpResponseRedirect(next)` to go to the page intended... Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You're sending the next parameter to the login view in my example, what's the problem?

Comment: I just modified the question please check an see if you can help. I think I communicated wrongly at first

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. I had to access the url in the `next` parameter like `{{request.GET.next}}` instead of `{{next}}`

So my code changed to :

In templates I added a hidden input to my login form and set its value to `{{request.GET.next}}`

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}" />
```

So in my login view, I could now access the hidden field's value and use it that value to do my redirection after login

```
def do_login(request):
form = LoginForm()# create an instance of a login form
logged_in =request.user.is_authenticated() # get login status

if logged_in:
    message='You are logged in '
    return render_to_response('reg/login.html',locals())# return  
if request.method == 'POST':
    usr=request.POST['username'] #get username
    passwrd=request.POST['password']# get password
    form=LoginForm(request.POST) # create instance of loginform
    user=authenticate(username=usr,password=passwrd)# authenticate user
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request,user) #log user in
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST['next'])
        else:
            pass
    else:
        return render_to_response('reg/login.html',locals())
else:
    return render_to_response('reg/login.html',locals())
```